# Difference between <?php echo $session_id ?> and <?= $session_id ?>

Tags: php

Is there any particular reason to use one over the other?  I personally tend to use the latter, as it just seems to flow better to me.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

They do the same thing, the <?= is just called the short tag and is shorthand for <?php echo.  You have to make sure the short tags are enabled to use the <?= notation.

Comment: It's also not compatible with XML-based docs (like Xhtml), since XML requires '<?' for it's own use.  Long tags '<?php' are compatible, and highly recommended for portability.

Comment: As the php.ini.dist files says: "NOTE: Using short tags should be avoided when developing applications or libraries that are meant for redistribution, or deployment on PHP servers which are not under your control, because short tags may not be supported on the target server....."

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know, they are functionally equivalent except the second can be disabled in configurations so isn't as portable.

Answer (score 1):

> `short_open_tag` boolean
>
> Tells whether the short form ( )
>   of PHP's open tag should be allowed.
>   If you want to use PHP in combination
>   with XML, you can disable this option
>   in order to use  inline.
>   Otherwise, you can print it with PHP,
>   for example:  . Also if disabled,
>   you must use the long form of the PHP
>   open tag ( ).
>
> Note: This directive also affects the
>   shorthand

[Source](http://ca.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.short-open-tag).

Comment: The correct answer imo. Though a quote could be posted in the text instead of just a link.

Answer (score 0):

The shorthand is clearer. It says, with as few words possible:

> "Here, an expressions is echoed and
>   nothing else is going on."

Answer (score 0):

Short tags are disabled on a significant amount of php installation so I never use

```
<?=$my_var?> // Bad Portability

<?php echo $my_var; ?> // Good Portability!
```

Answer (score 0):

I would assume that `<?php= $session_id; ?>` works fine, and does not have the issue of portability.

Answer (score 0):

Just an addon question. I've read a few years ago that using `<?` and `?>` is not recommended due to security issues. Is this correct?