# <?php instead of <?

Tags: php, syntax

Why should I use `<?php` instead of `<?` in my php script?

Comment: This is essentially a dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/436688/difference-between-php-echo-sessionid-and-sessionid

Comment: not really; that question is about shorttags (a quick way of echoing out variable contents), wheareas this is about the different tag conventions.

Comment: But the answers cause this to be a dupe.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The two main reasons to avoid the short opening tag are

1. Maximum portability - `<?php` will work on every PHP enabled server, but `<?` can be disabled
2. It's identical to the opening of the XML preamble - could cause parsing or execution headaches

Comment: The XML argument doesn't count. (http://hsivonen.iki.fi/producing-xml/). The XML argument is in the same category as deciding on a non-standard way to escape SQL strings. The PHP team made a big mistake and accidently killed this short tag feature.

Comment: Any server admin that disables <? should be shot.

Comment: Jasper, please don't advocate shooting people unless you're willing to look the target in the eye and pull the trigger yourself.

Comment: If by "shot" you mean "given a shot of his favorite liquor" then I agree.

Comment: OK. Perhaps shot is too strong a word, but punched, definitely

Comment: Ow please, is it really that much of a bother typing three extra characters? or writing a small script that replaces all short opening tags in your project with the decent ones? PS: all those advocating violence seem to prefer short opening tags... kind of says it all, doesn't it? :)

Comment: @Elias - Agreed when you're just coding code in php.  But when you use php in templates you really feel the pain of short_open_tag=off

Comment: @PeterBailey - 1 is only a problem because people are worried about 2.  And 2 is not a problem for 99.99% of the code out there. For those limit few where the xml is actually a problem - they should work around the problem - which is not hard.

Comment: @Yehosef - I just documented the "why" - I didn't make an argument that they're good reasons.

Answer (score 7):

There are two methods to start PHP

```
<?php
```

and

```
<?
```

PHP also includes

```
<?=
```

But that will print out the variable behind it, since its a shorthand for echo.

You should use < ?php since its compatible with all server types. You can move your code to a new hosting solution or setup a new server default and the shorthands could be disabled.

Answer (score 5):

The short tags `<?` (and `<?=`) could be disabled. The long version `<?php` (and `<?=` = `<?php echo`) work everywhere.

We could discuss the sense of this decision of the PHP team to make such a thing configurable, but the essence is, that you can't use the short tags in portable code.

Comment: why on earth would anyone disable the short tags?

Comment: @Orion Edwards: It's a config option. php.ini makes it really difficult to write portable code. More difficult than necessary. If it's an option, then it's taboo for portable code. :-(

Answer (score 3):

Both are semantically the same.  `<?` is simply a shortcut for the full syntax.

Comment: Nick.  that code I showed was for ASP.NET MVC and was simply an analogy

Comment: But it was an incorrect analogy.  PHP does provide a utility tag like ASP.Net does, but it is <?= as stated in my previous comment.  You corrected your answer so I +1ed you.

Comment: :) Sorry was trying an analogy that obviously failed. :)  Probably shouldn't have compared ASP.NET MVC which has the <%= for something different to PHP's <?=

Answer (score 3):

I personally prefer `<?`  to be switched off for two reasons

1. PHP Coding Standards across many big PHP project recommend it to be switched off
2. Creates problems if you are generating XML docs(xml docs begin with `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>`)
3. (bonus) `<?php` is more readable and prominently visible than `<?`.

Comment: #3 is a MISfeature. I want PHP to get out of my damn way, not make itself prominently visible

Answer (score 2):

To add to everyone's explanation that short tags should not be used because they might be disabled (or maybe even removed from future PHP versions), the main rationale for short tags to be deprecated is that they are not valid XML "Processing instructions" while the `<?php` tags are. So PHP templates with `<?php ... ?>` tags can be valid XML documents while those using the short tags are not.

- http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#sec-pi

Answer (score 1):

It should be noted that some server configurations of PHP do not support one or the other out of the box. For instance, my web server does not support <? but does support <?php

Comment: This is technically incorrect - ALL php installations support the normal (long) opening tag, whereas the short opening tag can be disabled.  To say "some do not support one or the other" is factually incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

The portability arguments are all well and good, but I'm going to be sacrilegious and say that you should go ahead and use short tags if you want to, unless you're doing something that is for really wide distribution (of the source), or are making something very xml focused.

a) I've never been in a situation where I couldn't enable short tags. Usually they're on by default.

b) In most situations, the `<?` is not going to get confused with `<?xml` because they're being parsed at different levels of the stack.

c) the short tag is less obtrusive and therefore clutters your code less. I find this especially true with `<?php echo` vs. `<?=`. (You could argue that you should generally avoid using either one of those, because it probably means you're writing spaghetti code, but come on -- this is php!)

Of course, it all depends on what kind of project you're working on, but for a basic web site, I don't think the short tag is at all likely to hurt you.

Comment: Yet in the future PHP short tags will not be enabled and all of your code will break with the next major release.

Comment: Is that true? Is there an official source for that?

Comment: On php.net, I see a recommendation to use long tags, which is fine, but I don't see anything official about short tags going away.

Answer (score 0):

[Wordpress Coding Standards](http://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Coding_Standards) says only use `<?php`.  They don't explain why.

This might be a religious question.

Comment: <?php makes code more portable, that's why WordPress Coding Standards recommend it.

Comment: I don't think Stack Overflow had comments when I gave this answer.

Answer (score 0):

The support of the short form `<?`/`<?=` syntax is based on the [`short_open_tag` parameter in php.ini](https://www.php.net/ini.core).  If you host your own codebase, this is trivial to enable.  However, on a shared/managed web host, you may not have control over this setting.

Thus, for maximum portability you should use the long form syntax.